# How to make NSWindow's toggleFullscreen behave synchronously (blocking)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Most NSWindow stuff is blocking except toggleFullScreen (among a few others) which is asynchronous and what's worse, it can fail too. This, coupled with a fact that calling close() on a fullscreen window is buggy[1], makes me want to wait on the window to enter/exit fullscreen before doing anything else (eg. I'd like to wait for the window to exit fullscreen before calling close()).

What would be a good way to do that (without polling on a timer which would be the obvious answer) ?

[1] it doesn't exit fullscreen mode leaving you staring at an empty gray screen, and, if you create another window after the first one is closed it will have the fullscreen flag set -- which surfaces the fact that this is actually a global flag under the hood.

Comment: why the negative vote?

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure what the actual issue is, I think I can offer some advice.

If you want to prevent the closing of a window between full screen and windowed mode, you can simply make a check against the delegate methods of NSWindow. [NSWindowDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/) provides methods such as `-windowDidExitFullScreen:` and `-windowWillExitFullScreen:` that should inform you when the window is going between states. Lastly, you can block the closing of the window with `-windowShouldClose:`.

Comment: I don't want to prevent closing, I need a way to _wait_ until the window is closed, and since it might be in fullscreen mode, this means a way to wait until the window exists fullscreen. I'm already using all these events.

Comment: eg. the Windows API gives you a choice between sync and async with ShowWindow() vs ShowWindowAsync() -- I want to emulate the sync (i.e. block, don't return from the call until the operation is done) version of toggleFullscreen(). Hope that's more clear.

Comment: yip. see my answer - that can make it 'work' like windows

Answer (score 0):

### how it is:

1. begin entering fullscreen
2. `windowDidEnterFullScreen` is called when it is done

### now you want to wait.

1b. have a boolean that keeps the state. (_windowIsInFullscreen). Set it to NO before, and to YES in the delegate message

1c. wait:

```
 while(!_windowIsInFullscreen) {
                    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:.5]];
            NSLog(@"Polling...");
 }
```

this is how modal stuff works too (IMHO this is bad though ;) async rules -- but that is personal preference)

Comment: async introduces race conditions even in the most trivial of cases (i.e. the sequence `foo(); bar()` becomes unpredictable if `bar()` tests a condition that is changed by `foo()` asynchronously. making `foo()` blocking would solve the problem.); anyway, I was specific in my question -- no polling on a timer please.

Comment: don't see any race condition here and that IS how modal stuff works ;) anyway - good luck then!

Comment: just to be clear - async != different threads. With different threads this WOULD be a race condition but we only have 1 thread here